# Can `pyproject.toml` be used for Python projects that aren't built?

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a number of data processing projects that are run as *cronjobs* and some APIs that are run as *systemd* services. In both of these cases, the Python projects are not built to be Python packages.

Lately, in my actual Python package projects, I have been really liking using `pyproject.toml` to manage dependencies and configurations. Some of the *pre-commits* like "*ruff*" also use `pyproject.toml` for their own configuration.

For a Python project that is not installed as a package, is it *pythonic* to include a `pyproject.toml`? Is it possible to do this without turning it into an installable package?

I have so far tried searching for similar answers but haven't seen any. Please let me know if the assumption that I should work towards is that I *should* turn all my projects into packages.

Comment: You can use it for configuration of other tools, this should be no problem at all. -- But for dependencies, I am not so sure, I guess it depends how you want to handle this, witch which tools. -- You can always make it a package, even if you do not use it as a package.

Comment: this has nothing to do with pre-commit. don't tag spam